How can I overcome AWS Glue's extreme memory limitations?
A Python Shell job cannot use more than one DPU. This means that it has a limit of 16 GB of memory.
Earlier today, I wired what I considered to be a modest ETL task to AWS Glue with 1 DPU. It was written in Python Shell. It ran for just over 10 minutes. In theory, this task queries a Microsoft SQL Server hosted in EC2 and produces 3,000,000 rows with about 250 columns and writes it to CSV. The CSV should come to about 2.5 GB. In practice, I get

Command Failed due to Out of Memory

from Glue. As far as I can tell, this error does not come from SQL; It comes from 1 DPU not being enough. Batching the queries and writes to CSV fixed this problem, but I did not wish to need to do that.
This confuses me very deeply. I do not consider 2.5 GB of data to be an unreasonable amount to ETL. As a person with a SQL background, I eat 2.5 GB for breakfast and I was doing this very same task in SSIS years ago. The Python does not do any complex manipulation of the data. It just grabs it from SQL and writes it to new CSV files on S3.
This gives me my question. AWS Glue is advertised as a cloud-scale ETL tool, but my experience described above indicates that it cannot manage modest ETL tasks. What am I missing and how can these limitations be overcome?

I think the main issue is that you are using a simple Python shell job and Python's memory management is not always optimized for handling large datasets efficiently. Is there a particular reason why you chose a shell job over a spark job for such memory-intensive data integration?

@ParmanM.Alizadeh Frankly, because we don't know any better. Every Glue task in the company is done in Python. I don't even know what Spark is.

A Spark job is run in an Apache Spark environment managed by AWS Glue. You can still write your code in Python (using pyspark) the only difference is the underlying infrastructure. It is well optimized for memory-intensive tasks and also comes with optimized built-in connectors for many database systems. see here: https://medium.com/@shuvradipghosh97/pyspark-for-aws-glue-a-comprehensive-guide-to-big-data-processing-407f921d3452

@ParmanM.Alizadeh Should I infer that nobody who knows what they're doing actually uses Python Shell in Glue?

Not really, python shell jobs just have a different use case and are used for less data-intensive tasks. while spark jobs can use up to 8 DPU (32 vCPUs, 128 GB of memory)

@ParmanM.Alizadeh Good to know. I've hunted through the GUI for ways to switch from Shell to Spark, but I can't find it. "Type" is set to "Python Shell" and simply won't change. I guess I need to do it the hard way and set up JDBC, as your link suggests.

How do you create your jobs? Through the console or do you use any infrastructure-as-code tools to set up your job?

@ParmanM.Alizadeh CloudFormation.

Ok I will post an answer using CloudFormation.

You can't really count the size of data you're processing in terms of the final CSV. The dataframe needs to be stored in python and then processed, and python probably has some overhead for every column etc, so i'm pretty sure 2.5gb is at the lower end of the estimation for that kind of dataset

The main issue is that you are using a simple Python shell job and Python's memory management is not always optimized for handling large datasets efficiently. In this case, you should configure your job to run on Spark engine.
A Spark job is run in an Apache Spark environment managed by AWS Glue. You can still write your code in Python (using pyspark) the only difference is the underlying infrastructure. It is well optimized for memory-intensive tasks and also comes with optimized built-in connectors for many database systems (see here for more details).
There are different ways you can create and configure a Glue job.
You can use the visual console to create a job, you need to navigate to AWS Glue -> ETL Jobs -> Create job -> Author code with a script editor. Then you have to set the engine to Spark like this:

If you are using CloudFormation or AWS CDK you need to specify the name under command to glueetl which will set spark as the engine, as opposed to setting it to pythonshell for python shell jobs.
CloudFormation example:
    MyJob:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Job
    Properties:
      Command:
        Name: glueetl
        ScriptLocation: "s3://<your-S3-script-uri>"
      DefaultArguments:
        "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-enable"
      ExecutionProperty:
        MaxConcurrentRuns: 2
      MaxRetries: 0
      Name: cf-job1
      Role: !Ref MyJobRole

AWS CDK example:
import aws_cdk.aws_glue as glue

        myjob= glue.CfnJob(
            self,
            "MyJob",
            command=glue.CfnJob.JobCommandProperty(
                name="glueetl",
                python_version="3",
                script_location="s3://<your-S3-script-uri>",
            ),
            role=MyJobRole,
            default_arguments={
                "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-disable",
               },
            execution_property=glue.CfnJob.ExecutionPropertyProperty(
                max_concurrent_runs=1
            ),
            glue_version="4.0",
            max_retries=0,
            name="cf-job1",
            number_of_workers=2,
            worker_type="G.1X"
            )

A simple job to read from a SQL Server database can be as follows:
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext, SparkConf
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glue_context = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glue_context.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

connection_sqlserver_options = {
    "url": "",
    "dbtable": "",
    "user": "",
    "password": ""}
    
df= glue_Context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="sqlserver",
                                                   connection_options=connection_sqlserver_options)

You can also use any custom connector by specifying the path to its .jar:
# Add the Spark SQL Server Connector package
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("path/to/spark-sqlserver-connector.jar")

# Read data from SQL Server using the Spark SQL Server Connector
df = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://your_sqlserver_host:1433;database=mydb") \
    .option("dbtable", "mytable") \
    .option("user", "your_username") \
    .option("password", "your_password") \
    .load()

# Write the data frame to S3 as Parquet files
s3_output_path = "s3://my-bucket/output/"
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s3_output_path)


Do the database connections need to be special in any particular way when setting them for Spark? I recall them needing something like JDBC. In Python Shell, I can get away with just wiring up subnets/VPCs and connecting through them.

@J.Mini Glue already have JDBC connectors for popular RDMS. But you can also specify it yourself as shown in the code. One other way is that if you already have a Glue Connection to your database, you can use a crawler to Catalog your source table and just use the cataloged table to directly read from it. let me know if this is your case and I'll update my answer to include this approach

@J.Mini Also on a sidenote, you can still use the same approach you used in vanilla python to connect to a database (e.g. pyodbc ) in the Spark glue job. But it is suggested to use the glue connectors for better efficiency.

Great news and terrible news. The great news is that I have Spark working with minimal changes to my initial code. It was far easier than I expected and I cannot thank you enough! I didn't even need to change connections/drivers! The terrible news is that I have still seemingly blew a limit on the same modest dataset. The new error message is "ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(77)): Unknown error from Python: Error Traceback is not available.".

@J.Mini It's very hard to understand the problem with no traceback of error and no actual code to reproduce. What is the glue version you are using?

Pretty sure it was 4.
